# visual studio, want to add reference assembly websocket from system.net.websockets .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, websocket

Am using **Visual Studio Community 2017**.

Trying to reference `.net framework Websockets`, link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets?view=netframework-4.5

Though am unable to find this file from `Nuget`, or from `

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

`

Should I be downloading the raw `dll` file and to add to the local folder?

Please help I am stuck and just want to use the `microsoft APIs`, and wondering why is microsoft API so tough to use...

**EDIT 1:**
After some further testing with help of friends of stack overflow, I realised some mistakes that I had which led to my miscommunication of question.

Firstly, whilst browsing through the `object browser` in `Visual Studio`, the `reference assembly` packages would show the functions within, however when I reference the packages from `Nuget`, none of the functions appear, wherein I thought that the package was not loaded.

However, it has actually been loaded already and will work, I just required to set the target framework to 4.6.0 such that it works with the nuget package linked by accepted answer.

Comment: _"...Though am unable to find this file from Nuget.."_ - _[Didn't look too hard....first hit](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=nuget+System.Net.WebSockets&oq=nuget+System.Net.WebSockets&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j35i39l2j0l2.1262j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)_.

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question wrongly, as am new to microsoft's coding base, there is a .net framework / .net core. From what is researched, the package you guys are referring to are referencing the .net core. 

So am wondering how can I get the System.net.websockets from the .net framework as my project references the .net framework and not .net core.

Comment: _"..the package you guys are referring to are referencing the .net core"_ - incorrect.  **System.Net.WebSockets** is not part of the .NET Framework.  It is a NuGet package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Websocket is already available here ,you just need to install this package by going

**tools > nuget package manager > Package Manager Console**

> Install-Package System.Net.WebSockets -Version 4.3.0

Comment: isn't this package making use of .Net Core?